# Node passport flow with Express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I' learning Node.s and Express, and I'm following this example from https://github.com/EvanHahn/Express.js-in-Action-code/tree/master/Chapter_08/learn-about-me. Can you explain the following question?

1. In the "/login" post route, if I need to access the **request and response** objects, how should I do it?
2. What is the "**done**" function inside LocalStrategy(), and how I know what parameter to pass? Looks like it take 3 arguments, and the 2nd argument is the user object, and the 3rd argument is the message. What is the 1st argument?
3. How do the **username and password** get passed from the "/login" post route into LocalStrategy? What magic is behind the scene?

```js
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("login", {
  successRedirect: "/",
  failureRedirect: "/login",
  failureFlash: true
}));
```

```html
passport.use("login", new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: "No user has that username!" });
      }
      user.checkPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (isMatch) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password." });
        }
      });
    });
  }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for question #1 and #2 is at http://passportjs.org/docs

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

## 3 is at the same docs page.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'passwd'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    // ...
  }
));
```